# Finding Adjacent Rows With Two Sets

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data sample table.  I need to figure out how to group by repeating Eventtypes by the tskid.  * I CANNOT use stored procedures nor loops.  Basically for each eventtype group in each tskid, I would like the use the first instance startdate as startdate, and the last instance startdate of each repeating group as the end date.  Please see below for the output I want. Thank you!

```
DATA:
with test as (
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20100928' AS STARTDATE,'14174646' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20100928' AS STARTDATE,'16071919' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20100929' AS STARTDATE,'300303' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20100930' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20100930' AS STARTDATE,'10542121' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20100930' AS STARTDATE,'11021516' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20100930' AS STARTDATE,'13323839' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20100930' AS STARTDATE,'16265253' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20100930' AS STARTDATE,'16580202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20100930' AS STARTDATE,'17014949' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101001' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101001' AS STARTDATE,'10052525' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101001' AS STARTDATE,'10423434' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101004' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101004' AS STARTDATE,'17540506' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype
FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101020' AS STARTDATE,'10003132' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101020' AS STARTDATE,'12105253' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101021' AS STARTDATE,'300303' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101022' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101025' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101026' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101027' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101028' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101029' AS STARTDATE,'300303' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101101' AS STARTDATE,'300303' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101101' AS STARTDATE,'12280606' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101101' AS STARTDATE,'12284444' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101102' AS STARTDATE,'300303' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101103' AS STARTDATE,'300303' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101104' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101105' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101105' AS STARTDATE,'10223636' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101105' AS STARTDATE,'13371212' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101108' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101109' AS STARTDATE,'300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101110' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101111' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101112' AS STARTDATE,'300303' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101115' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101116' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101117' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101118' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101119' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101122' AS STARTDATE,'300303' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101122' AS STARTDATE,'10134748' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101122' AS STARTDATE,'11554646' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101123' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101123' AS STARTDATE,'17024243' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101124' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101126' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101129' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101130' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101201' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101202' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101203' AS STARTDATE,'300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101206' AS STARTDATE,'300303' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101207' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101208' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101209' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101210' AS STARTDATE,'300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101213' AS STARTDATE,'300303' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101214' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101215' AS STARTDATE,'300303' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101216' AS STARTDATE,'300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101217' AS STARTDATE,'300303' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101220' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101221' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101222' AS STARTDATE,'300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101223' AS STARTDATE,'300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101227' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101228' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101229' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101230' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20101231' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110103' AS STARTDATE,'300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110104' AS STARTDATE,'300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110105' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110106' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110107' AS STARTDATE,'300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110110' AS STARTDATE,'300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110111' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110112' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110113' AS STARTDATE,'300303' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110114' AS STARTDATE,'300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110118' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110119' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110120' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110121' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110124' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110125' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110126' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110127' AS STARTDATE,'300303' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110128' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110131' AS STARTDATE,'300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110201' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110202' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110203' AS STARTDATE,'300303' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110204' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110608' AS STARTDATE,'15531212' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110620' AS STARTDATE,'17202222' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110623' AS STARTDATE,'9293273' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110623' AS STARTDATE,'10415757' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110623' AS STARTDATE,'10420183' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110623' AS STARTDATE,'14460845' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110624' AS STARTDATE,'9213939' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110624' AS STARTDATE,'9214444' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110708' AS STARTDATE,'8040505' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110801' AS STARTDATE,'12153434' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110801' AS STARTDATE,'14171313' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110808' AS STARTDATE,'11464092' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110808' AS STARTDATE,'16123640' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110809' AS STARTDATE,'9195607' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110809' AS STARTDATE,'9201911' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110809' AS STARTDATE,'11542121' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110912' AS STARTDATE,'9041752' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110912' AS STARTDATE,'9055948' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110912' AS STARTDATE,'16391168' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110912' AS STARTDATE,'16393185' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110913' AS STARTDATE,'14025206' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110915' AS STARTDATE,'9182121' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110915' AS STARTDATE,'9525454' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110915' AS STARTDATE,'11300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110915' AS STARTDATE,'14334444' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110915' AS STARTDATE,'14345757' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110919' AS STARTDATE,'12172020' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110919' AS STARTDATE,'13082020' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110920' AS STARTDATE,'6582929' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110923' AS STARTDATE,'13595050' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110927' AS STARTDATE,'17153636' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110928' AS STARTDATE,'9325757' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110929' AS STARTDATE,'17480404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20110930' AS STARTDATE,'13290808' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111003' AS STARTDATE,'7243939' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111003' AS STARTDATE,'7410673' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111003' AS STARTDATE,'11191818' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111011' AS STARTDATE,'14302626' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111013' AS STARTDATE,'20042101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111017' AS STARTDATE,'16352837' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111019' AS STARTDATE,'10573030' AS TIMEOFDAY,'7' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111021' AS STARTDATE,'16181581' AS TIMEOFDAY,'7' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111025' AS STARTDATE,'14332020' AS TIMEOFDAY,'7' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111027' AS STARTDATE,'14404242' AS TIMEOFDAY,'7' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111027' AS STARTDATE,'15301212' AS TIMEOFDAY,'7' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111027' AS STARTDATE,'15303030' AS TIMEOFDAY,'7' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111028' AS STARTDATE,'16514829' AS TIMEOFDAY,'7' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111031' AS STARTDATE,'7401717' AS TIMEOFDAY,'7' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111107' AS STARTDATE,'14444343' AS TIMEOFDAY,'7' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111107' AS STARTDATE,'14444848' AS TIMEOFDAY,'3' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111107' AS STARTDATE,'14480101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'3' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111107' AS STARTDATE,'16311272' AS TIMEOFDAY,'4' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111108' AS STARTDATE,'13331919' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111111' AS STARTDATE,'9433080' AS TIMEOFDAY,'3' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111111' AS STARTDATE,'14540246' AS TIMEOFDAY,'4' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbd123' AS TSKID,'20111114' AS STARTDATE,'7511220' AS TIMEOFDAY,'0' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tvt003' AS TSKID,'20110509' AS STARTDATE,'10442063' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tvt003' AS TSKID,'20110509' AS STARTDATE,'10502891' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tvt003' AS TSKID,'20111012' AS STARTDATE,'8333340' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tvt003' AS TSKID,'20111013' AS STARTDATE,'13122884' AS TIMEOFDAY,'7' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tvt003' AS TSKID,'20111013' AS STARTDATE,'13420329' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tvt003' AS TSKID,'20111014' AS STARTDATE,'13381646' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tvt003' AS TSKID,'20111018' AS STARTDATE,'12451804' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tvt003' AS TSKID,'20111019' AS STARTDATE,'14091263' AS TIMEOFDAY,'3' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tvt003' AS TSKID,'20111021' AS STARTDATE,'12355005' AS TIMEOFDAY,'4' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tvt003' AS TSKID,'20111021' AS STARTDATE,'12373030' AS TIMEOFDAY,'4' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tvt003' AS TSKID,'20111024' AS STARTDATE,'10203700' AS TIMEOFDAY,'8' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tvt003' AS TSKID,'20111101' AS STARTDATE,'12513479' AS TIMEOFDAY,'34' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tvt003' AS TSKID,'20111101' AS STARTDATE,'13440810' AS TIMEOFDAY,'35' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tvt003' AS TSKID,'20111107' AS STARTDATE,'14094345' AS TIMEOFDAY,'0' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101112' AS STARTDATE,'13061818' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101112' AS STARTDATE,'13173636' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101115' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101115' AS STARTDATE,'9215050' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101116' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101117' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101118' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101119' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101119' AS STARTDATE,'11311616' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101119' AS STARTDATE,'15463839' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101122' AS STARTDATE,'300303' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101123' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101124' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101124' AS STARTDATE,'15183838' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101124' AS STARTDATE,'15302122' AS TIMEOFDAY,'32' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101124' AS STARTDATE,'15312324' AS TIMEOFDAY,'32' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101124' AS STARTDATE,'15313233' AS TIMEOFDAY,'11' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101124' AS STARTDATE,'15314041' AS TIMEOFDAY,'10' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101124' AS STARTDATE,'15315354' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101124' AS STARTDATE,'15320506' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101126' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101129' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101130' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101201' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101202' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101203' AS STARTDATE,'300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101206' AS STARTDATE,'300303' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101206' AS STARTDATE,'10000808' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101206' AS STARTDATE,'10011718' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101206' AS STARTDATE,'10240203' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101207' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101208' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101216' AS STARTDATE,'10344243' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101216' AS STARTDATE,'10384748' AS TIMEOFDAY,'0' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101216' AS STARTDATE,'10391919' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101216' AS STARTDATE,'10392122' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101216' AS STARTDATE,'10420303' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101216' AS STARTDATE,'13041819' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101217' AS STARTDATE,'300303' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101217' AS STARTDATE,'8550707' AS TIMEOFDAY,'32' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101217' AS STARTDATE,'8552323' AS TIMEOFDAY,'11' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101217' AS STARTDATE,'8554141' AS TIMEOFDAY,'10' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101217' AS STARTDATE,'8555757' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101217' AS STARTDATE,'8561313' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101217' AS STARTDATE,'8583333' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101220' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101220' AS STARTDATE,'8062021' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101221' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101222' AS STARTDATE,'300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101223' AS STARTDATE,'300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101227' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101228' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101229' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101230' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20101231' AS STARTDATE,'300202' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20110103' AS STARTDATE,'300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20110104' AS STARTDATE,'300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20110104' AS STARTDATE,'8573737' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20110104' AS STARTDATE,'8574040' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20110104' AS STARTDATE,'8583536' AS TIMEOFDAY,'23' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20110105' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'23' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20110106' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'23' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20110106' AS STARTDATE,'9064040' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20110107' AS STARTDATE,'300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20110107' AS STARTDATE,'12255252' AS TIMEOFDAY,'2' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20110107' AS STARTDATE,'12255455' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20110110' AS STARTDATE,'300000' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20110111' AS STARTDATE,'300101' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20110111' AS STARTDATE,'14034343' AS TIMEOFDAY,'30' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20110111' AS STARTDATE,'14265859' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20110111' AS STARTDATE,'15265656' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20110111' AS STARTDATE,'16203939' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20110111' AS STARTDATE,'16322424' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'txs472' AS TSKID,'20110112' AS STARTDATE,'300404' AS TIMEOFDAY,'1' AS Eventtype FROM DUAL UNION)

OUTPUT:
TSKID   StartDate  EndDate   Eventtype
tbd123  20100928   20100930  2
tbd123  20100930   20101004  30
tbd123  20101020   20101122  2  and so on....same for all other tskids
```

Comment: You have provided a lot of code here, please consider revising your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Bluefeet,  I don't have access to create a table, and I wanted to make it easier for people to answer my question.  But, I also wanted people to be more aware the patterns in the data.

Answer (score 1):

Is this in the ballpark of what you want? I don't have oracle to test with so I'm using a competitor:

```
with test (
...
)
select TSKID
     , min(STARTDATE) as min_startdate
     , max(STARTDATE) as max_startdate
     , Eventtype
     , grp
from (
    select TSKID, STARTDATE, Eventtype
        ,  row_number() over (partition by tskid order by STARTDATE)
         - row_number() over (partition by tskid, Eventtype order by STARTDATE) as grp
    from test
)
group by TSKID,Eventtype,grp
order by TSKID,Eventtype
```

Comment: Thinking along the same lines *8-) I get duplicates back with `row_number()` unless I change `from test` to `from (select distinct tskid, startdate, eventtype from test)`. But the results are still different - this breaks it down more; 27 rows for `tbd123` versus 17 with `dense_rank`. Not sure which is correct.

Comment: Alex, you are probably right. I did not have time to investigate it more closely, so I just added a sketch that the OP could work with

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.

```
with test as (...),
t as (
  select tskid, startdate, eventtype,
    dense_rank() over (partition by tskid order by startdate)
     - dense_rank() over (partition by tskid, eventtype order by startdate)
    as chain
  from test
)
select tskid, min(startdate) as startdate, max(startdate) as enddate,
  eventtype
from t
group by tskid, eventtype, chain
order by tskid, startdate;

TSKID  STARTDATE ENDDATE  EVENTTYPE
------ --------- -------- ---------
tbd123 20100928  20100930 2         
tbd123 20100930  20101004 30        
tbd123 20101020  20101122 2         
tbd123 20101122  20110608 30        
tbd123 20110620  20110623 2         
tbd123 20110623  20110624 1         
tbd123 20110623  20110912 30        
...
```

The subquery (CTE) `t` identifies the contiguous groups of each `tskid`/`eventtype` combination using a trick comparing two `dense_rank` calculations.

You can then get the min and max `startdate` for each chain.

You can also use `row_number()`, but that has to be based on the distinct values for those, as the multiple `timeofday` fields throw it out otherwise; and it gives you a slightly different breakdown, as I commented on @Lennart's answer:

```
...
    row_number() over (partition by tskid order by startdate)
     - row_number() over (partition by tskid, eventtype order by startdate)
    as chain
  from (select distinct tskid, startdate, eventtype from test)
...

TSKID  STARTDATE ENDDATE  EVENTTYPE
------ --------- -------- ---------
tbd123 20100928  20100930 2         
tbd123 20100930  20101004 30        
tbd123 20101020  20101119 2         
tbd123 20101122  20101122 2         
tbd123 20101122  20101122 30        
tbd123 20101123  20110608 30        
tbd123 20110620  20110620 2         
tbd123 20110623  20110623 1         
tbd123 20110623  20110623 2         
tbd123 20110623  20110623 30        
...
```

Not sure which you want, or indeed if either is quote right; `dense_rank` seems to match the sample output in the question but not sure if that means much.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses.  I think the dense rank() is working well for me.